# Assigning multiple values in a single statement

Tags: c#

Consider this bit of code:

```
class X
{
     int _value;
     public object Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = Convert.ToInt32(value); } }
}

X x = new X();
object y = x.Value = 2.3;
```

To me it looks like `y == 2.0` because that is the return value of `x.Value`, but it turns out that it is `y == 2.3`, even though `x.Value == 2`.

Why?

Comment: Thanks, Skeet's answer explains it well. It's the wrong way of doing it though if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
object y = x.Value = 2.3;
```

is equivalent to

```
object y = 2.3;
x.Value = 2.3;
```

so, you will get result

```
y = 2.3
x.Value = 2
```

**UPDATE**

Some additional information after research of IL code:

Well, we have float value `2.3`. The `y` and `x.Value` expects object type. In this case:

- compiller declares a new variable let's call it `V` (`object V`).
- push onto the stack float value `2.3`
- boxing this value to object
- duplicates the value on the top of the stack. So, we will have 2 the same boxed values in stack (#1, #2).
- pop #2 and assign it to `V`
- assign `x.Value = V` (inside property value will be converted to `int`)
- pop #1 and assign it to `V`
- assign `y = V`

As a result we have something like this:

```
object V = (object)2.3;
x.Value = V;
y = V;
```

Comment: That's not true. According to the C# standard, `a = b = c;` is equivalent to `a = (b = c);`, because the assignment operators are right-associative. See section 7.17 of the standard. Although the standard seems a little flaky in this area...

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's just asigning the values at the same time, not one after another.

In other words when you write

```
object y = x.Value = 2.3;
```

It is interpreted as

```
x.Value = 2.3; 
object y = 2.3;
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of this piece of code:

`x.Value = 2.3`

is not `x.Value`. The getter is not run. The assignment operator returns the value to be assigned so that multiple assignment is possible.

The order of execution goes like this:

First, 2.3 is assigned to `X.value`. We don't care what the setter does with it, the statement `(X.value = 2.3)` returns the value 2.3

Second the returned statement from (X.value = 2.3) gets assigned to `y`

This concept is what makes multiple assignment look like two independent assignments:

```
X.value = 2.3
object y = 2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator assigns the value of the right-hand operand to the variable on the left, and **returns the assigned value**. It does not fetch the new value of the variable or property.